# how to write a jquery event handler for dependent auto - complete fields?

Tags: jquery, forms, autocomplete, event-handling, keypress

I have a form with 2 text fields which get populated using auto complete. Now when I enter some value in form 1 (through autocomplete ), I want the second form field to fetch the auto complete values using text entered in field1 as one of the parameters. Lets say ,

text 1 < contains car brand names which are auto populated >

text 2 < models of all cars again auto populated > ( key = car brand )

After entering the value in text 1 e.g Ford , I want to trigger an event which will load the auto fill in text2 taking 'Ford' as key i.e load all cars belonging to 'Ford' 
( all auto fills happen through ajax calls for me )

Which is the best event trigger ( keypress , keyup or onchange ) which I should use to achieve this seamlessly without any time lags or sync issues ?

Let me know if I am not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <input type="text" name="text1" value="whatever" id="text1" />
 <input type="text" name="text2" value="whatever" id="text2" />
```

Now you can use JQuery like this:

```
 $("#text1").blur(function(){
    $("#text2").val = $(this).val();
 });
```

I have used <kbd>blur</kbd> event here but you can use corresponding <kbd>keypress</kbd>, <kbd>change</kbd> as per your requirement.

Comment: why are you invoking val() on text 1 again inside the event handler ? Also keypress on text1 won't help much since it would keep triggering the auto fill on text 2 with every character entered in text 1

Comment: @Akshay: I have fixed it already, by the way what event you think is most appropriate for you?

Comment: and as i said you can use any other elements in my answer as per your requirement.

Comment: ignore my first line as it was for the first revision of your post . But rest of my post still remains valid.

Comment: key press on text 1 would still not do the job for me . keypress on text 2 would although be more efficient for auto fill but then if you are traversing through keys like 'Tab' , 'Shift Tab' doesnt load .

Comment: I suppose blur would do the trick as would onfocus out on text1. Let me see if it is able to handle sync issues or time lag as in case of keypress or keyup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax to get the complete dataset and then insert the data to the form by using js something like:

```
jQuery("#formID").value('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use "focusout" event on the first text box.

```
$('#text_box_one').focusout(function() {
  //Your auto-complete code goes here.
  //Or preferably replace this inline function with a call to an auto-complete function
});
```